# difference in postgres and redshift query

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

1> works fine in AWS RedShift :

```
rep=# \d repdaily
                   Table "prod.repdaily"
          Column           |  Type   |     Modifiers      
---------------------------+---------+--------------------
 timestamp                 | integer | not null default 0


rep=# SELECT distinct trunc(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + ((floor(timestamp/86400))*86400) *INTERVAL '1 second') as Date_New FROM repdaily limit 1;
  date_new  
------------
 2016-06-26
(1 row)

rep=# select version();
                                                         version                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1096
(1 row)

rep=#
```

2>I tried running same query in both 9.5.4 and 8.0.2:

I am not sure how to make it generic so that we can run it any where.

```
rep=# \d repdaily
                   Table "prod.repdaily"
          Column           |  Type   |     Modifiers      
---------------------------+---------+--------------------
 timestamp                 | integer | not null default 0

rep=# 
rep=# SELECT distinct trunc(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + ((floor(timestamp/86400))*86400) *INTERVAL '1 second') as Date_New FROM repdaily limit 1;
ERROR:  function trunc(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT distinct trunc(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + ((floor(timestamp/...
                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
rep=#

rep=# select version();
                                                 version                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.5.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17), 64-bit
(1 row)

rep=# 

rep=# select version();
                                                  version                                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
(1 row)

rep=#
```

Comment: It's `date_trunc()` in Postgres, not just `trunc()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have a `trunc(timestamp)` function native. Looking at RedShift's [`trunc(timestamp)` function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRUNC.html) you can see:

> The function can also return the date from a time stamp.
>   For time stamps, TRUNC returns a date.

So the equivalent for PostgreSQL would be a simple cast to a DATE type:

```
SELECT distinct
    CAST(TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + ((floor(timestamp/86400))*86400) *INTERVAL '1 second' AS date) as Date_New
FROM repdaily limit 1;
```

If you want, you can simple create this `trunc(timestamp)` function in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trunc(timestamp)
RETURNS date
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE AS $$
    SELECT $1::date;
$$;
```

Now your original query will also work in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Sorry, i was on long vacation and couldn't reply.
MatheusOl @ best answer i got if i'm not wrong and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much for you help!!!!